# Sharing Material UI to plugins

Tags: material-ui

We are creating an application based on your very impressive framework, we have plugins that load, and currently we ensure not to build the plugins with the entire Material-ui framework again, and instead share the instance from the main application.  We do this by attaching the components to the window global object so the plugins can reference and use them. This works really well, but was wondering if there is a better or more correct solution to share the entire framework with the plugins, as we need to keep adding components on a need to know basis when a new plugin needs access to another component not yet added to the window object.

So for example, main app :
window['TextField'] = TextField;

And when the plugin is loaded and executed can create a react component by using this reference, for example :

```
render() {
    const TextField = window['TextField'];
    return <TextField .... />;
}
```

So as a summary, is there a better solution, or is there away we can iterate over the entire core  components so we can add them all to the window global ?

Yours Sincerely and thanks for you help in advance.
Jason

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, what you actually want is "reusable components". For across project using, you can give some below things a try:

- Publish your desired component into `npm`, then use in another projects, packages, etc, whatever you want.
- Use https://bit.dev/

Basically the core idea are the same way you did with window variable: we need a global place to store the reusable thing.

Comment: Not exactly what I was asking, probably my bad description, Ill try and explain it better, our product uses material ui, and we also allow custom plugins to be loaded on the fly via our program, that share material ui, but don't want to build the plugin with material ui dependent components directly in the plugin itself, but instead use the shared material ui components in the host application itself. Basically not allowing duplicate components loaded at the same time.

Comment: Oh, I willing to help for sure, but could not find out your actually problem is. My bad :(